# How to deploy a DAO on Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, dao

Want to deploy and operate a Decentralized Autonomous Organization (DAO) on Ethereum.  What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options for you out there. But one of the best places to start with is **[Aragon](https://aragon.org/?pk_campaign=se&pk_kwd=se1)**. They have a very active community and legit Github activity.

Aragon's stack is quite modular and easy to play around with. They have Solidity framework for governance, an API and Package Manager along with a pretty slick looking UI for Dapps.

To get started, head straight to their developer portal: https://hack.aragon.org/